# Cannot get current session

Tags: spring, hibernate

`   
    
        
            classpath:database.properties

```
<bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">

    <property name="dataSource">
        <ref bean="dataSource" />
    </property>

    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
        </props>
    </property>

    <property name="packagesToScan" value="org.entity">

    </property>

</bean>
<bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"></property>

</bean>
<tx:annotation-driven/>
<!-- not working -->
<!-- <context:component-scan base-package="org.service"></context:component-scan> -->
```

`
this is my spring configuration file. Problem is that i am not getting current session in my repository classes which are marked with @Repository, I have annotated my service methods with @Transactional annotation.
However all the autowiring is working fine, the only problem is when i try to get current session in repository classes, and if I use bean tag to instantiate my repository and service beans it works. What am i doing wrong here?

Comment: Please post questions with specific code, as to how "i am not getting current session in my repository classes". No code has been supplied to show how/where the error occurs. Voting to close.

Answer (score 0):

Use the OpenSessionInView Filter or similar, that way you should have a Session available during the request lifecycle (Controller/ View rendering).

Comment: I dont think if i really need something like that. any way i am getting session when using bean tag. I should be able to get session here. damn what the hell is going wrong

Comment: How do you get the Session in your @Repository classes? Show us. And if you don't use OpenSessionInView, how do you expect lazy-loading to work in your JSP pages?

Comment: I dont want any lazy loading in my jsp pages, I will initialize my entity classes in service layer if i want any lazy data. My question is, if it is required to implement a filter to initialize session then how come it works when i create beans using tag in XML configuration file?

Comment: "I will initialize my entities in service layer if I want any lazy data" == presentation layer entanglement in service layer (service layer has to know what presentation's requirements are).

Comment: You should ask, like I asked before, __how you get the Session__ in your @Repository classes. And where the beans come from, that you expect to be auto-configured.  But hey, I'm kinda busy & all my Spring & Hibernate apps work -- perhaps you can research the question a bit further yourself.

Comment: I have a strong doubt with OpenSessionInView, I have my service methods marked @Transactional, it means session will be managed by transaction manager. After implementing OpenSessionInView how my transactions will be managed, where will the commit and rollback take place? I want them to happen in service layer. How can i keep session open just to get lazy fetch data in views?